# View reuse for ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

So I have inheritied a program (APPLE) whose code baseline originated on another program (ORANGE). In order to make it easier for multiple teams to update this code we are moving the 'common' stuff out into a Shared Project (TREE). So far, we have made this work great with pulling out the Models and Controllers to a Shared library (obviously a few Models/Controllers remain in ORANGE as they are specific to that application).

However, I'm hitting a wall on how to extract the Views. The idea would be that the Shared Library (TREE) contains the common views (like file import, and landing page) while leaving the program specific code behind in the 'main' ASP.net application (APPLE/ORANGE).

I found [this](https://www.ryansouthgate.com/2017/07/21/asp-net-core-mvc-common-components-view-across-applications/) article which looked really good. Except 1) I don't have Microsoft.AspNetCore Nuget (My Microsoft.AspNet.[package] don't appear to have ViewComponent), 2) When creating a new Web MVC project, it doesn't have a wwwroot, Program.cs, or the .json files. I also found another article talking about using VirtualFiles, but it doesn't really indicate where the EmbeddedResource class would reside, and (I could be mis-understanding) but it seems to look for all the Views in the vitural location.

So what is the best way to split common views out into the Shared Project I've created and utilize them in our program application?

This is an ASP.net application using MVC. It is not a Razor application.

I have access to Microsoft.AspNet.(various packages) and DevExpress.(various packages), but must go through a process to obtain other packages (so I can't easily download a package and test out suggestions).

Comment: All, just to clarify off the answer that was voted correct. I was able to move the Controller and Views to an external project. Ensure it (specifically the views) don't reference anything outside that project. Then you can generate a nuget package of that library. Upon import into your main project, the Views will be loaded into the View folder while the controller logic can be referenced normally via dot notation (MyProj.Controller.something). Note: you are unable to distinquish loaded Views from project views. Unloading nuget package will remove unmodified Views it imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply make your own NuGet package which, when installed into any project, adds the shared views, controllers and any other files you want.

We've done that successfully in my organisation to effectively provide a base template for any new MVC applications. It adds certain specific views and templates, overrides the layout view, sets up a controller and adds some global filters. It also adds some CSS and JavaScript files, so we've got ready-made corporate branding on the app, consistent shared functionality provided, and so on. It also depends on some other of our nuget packages which are then also loaded into the project, which provide shared functionality such as error handling, logging services, pre-made data connections, an API client and other bits and pieces which we need in almost every app we write.

The package itself is built from a separate project which is also source-controlled like any other codebase, and we maintain numbered versions.

This works very well as a way of sharing code and components between projects. It also means that any updates can be pushed out to all applications with minimal fuss.

Your nuget package could be installed manually into the project, or served from your own feed - you can create private NuGet feeds in Azure DevOps and other places, or even just a folder on a shared drive can be used as a package source, if you have to.

(P.S. That article you've linked to is about .NET Core, whereas you're using .NET Framework. The project structures are significantly different, hence your confusion.)

Comment: do you have any good articles that could provide a starting point for building your code as a Nuget package, and refrencing it in the code?
I think my big question would be how do I refrence the views coming from the nuget package. For example if I wanted to call nuget.Views\Import.cshtml.

I like the suggestion, I'm just not sure where to start on the implementation.

Comment: " For example if I wanted to call nuget.Views\Import.cshtml"...it would be no different to any other view. Installing the nuget package simply copies the cshtml files into your Views folder (or, ideally, a suitable subfolder). From then on, you treat them as a standard part of your application, as if you'd created them in that project to begin with. (The only difference is, if you were to then install a newer version of the package, the files would then be updated, so it's best not to modify them within the project if you can help it).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio-net-framework - this guide shows the basics of creating a package (follow it up to the bit about publishing - I'm assuming you don't want to publish to the public nuget.org feed). If you put other non-cs files in your project (e.g. cshtml, js, css etc) then set their Build Action to "Content" and they'll be included in the nuget package when you pack it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-visual-studio-project is also a handy guide.

Comment: Also, the Nuget Package Explorer (https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) is a really handy tool for examining the contents of the packages you build, and checking they include what you want them to, before you try to install them in a project!